# Get wind of in the TV series "Suits"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

I was watching Suits S02E02, and here's the dialogue.
The plot in short is that Harvey and Mike were trying to close another senior partner Paul's client and this client denied filing bankruptcy (even though he should), which was giving Paul a hard time. Harvey and Mike tried to think of some clever yet not 100% illegal ways to tackle the problem but was found out by Paul.

> Harvey: That's doubtful. He got wind of our little maneuver.
>   Mike: [laugh].
>   Harvey: What?
>   Mike: You said "got wind".

I knew that "got wind of sth" means to find out about sth secret or private but I don't get it why Mike laughed at the phrasing of Harvey right here.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the show, but — the phrase “break wind” means to pass gas (i.e., to fart).   Perhaps Mike was amused that Harvey said something similar to “break wind”.

Answer (score 1):

Aha.  Well.  This is a phrase with a double meaning.

Yes, one meaning is certainly 
*"to hear of something someone else wants to keep secret"*, but another meaning is to *"have gas"* or *"be gassy"*, which is to say, to be *"likely to [fart](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fart) a lot"*.

The use of airy metaphors to describe farting is, I think pretty common among languages.  Anyway the joke is pretty juvenile humor -- which doesn't mean it isn't *funny*, in the right context ...

Comment: And then there's *get the wind up about something*.